# Implementing an infinite scroll news feed graph model

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, gremlin, feed

I am building a social networking kind of website. I am using Python and OrientDB. What I am trying to do is to fetch the posts of all the users (`user2`, `user3`, `user4`, etc) who are connected to say `user1` and show those posts in the news feed of `user1`.

For this, I am using the Graphity model to retrieve the top 'K' news feed efficiently. But, the challenge comes in when, for example the users scrolls down and all the top 'K' feeds are shown to him already. Now I want to fetch from exactly where 'K' was left off, ie. 'K+1', 'K+2', etc. What is the right or efficient way to do this?

I can think of retrieving the top '2K' news feed again, and then when that's consumed, retrieve top '3K' feeds and so on. But, as you can see, it is very heavy to do that.

Is there any predefined solution to this problem or some solution that you can think of, so that I can continue fetching the posts from where I left, once the top 'K' feeds are retrieved first.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use a linkmap if you wish to store mixed values. It will be more efficient cause you won't have to traverse through the whole list. By experimenting, I found that you can expand an array of keys and it's really efficient !

Here is how the syntax looks like :

```
select expand(feed[3-5]) from <#user:id>
```

For your infinite scroll, you can build a query in a server side function that selects the items at the positions you want :-) If the keys represent positions in the map, you can get the position of the last element in the map and use it to fetch the last x elements.

The squared brackets allow to :

- filtering by one index, example out()[0]
- filtering by multiple indexes, example out()[0,2,4]
- filtering by ranges, example out()[0-9]

Here is an exemple, using [OrientGraph](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/impls/orient/OrientGraph.html) in an [OrientDB function](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/wiki/Functions#functions) :

**Fetching mecanism**

First, get the last key value with a [command](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/wiki/Functions#sql-command) :

```
var lastKey = db.command("sql","select last(feed.keys()) as lastKey from <#user:id>")[0].getRecord().toMap()["lastKey"];`
```

Second, execute the query with the keys you want :

```
return db.command("sql","select expand(feed[" + (parseInt(lastKey) -20).toString() + "-" +  lastKey + "]) from <#user:id>");
```

**Insert mechanism**

First, get the last key value :

```
var lastKey = db.command("sql","select last(feed.keys()) as lastKey from <#user:id>")[0].getRecord().toMap()["lastKey"];`
```

Second, [put](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/wiki/SQL-Update#example-5-put-a-map-entry-into-a-map) the new element at the last key value incremented by 1 :

```
db.command("sql","update <user-id> put feed = \""(parseInt(lastKey) + 1).toString()"\", <#newelem:id>
```

Hope you like my solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think this is what I do with the `Graphity` model. The posts are already stored in their reverse chronological order (ie. linked with `has_previous_post` kind of relationships), hence not needing to retrieve them ordered using dates. What I want here is to know, if I get the first few feeds for the user, and later the user needs to get the feeds posted before the ones he has seen already, I should be able to fetch only from where I left previously, efficiently. This needs to be done either in the DB level or if it isn't possible, the application level.

Comment: Can you edit you're question and add how your schema looks like ?

Comment: So, what you mean is "Set a pointer to the last retrieved news feed and store it in the User node. Then, start from the news feed the next time." Isn't it?

Comment: No, you don't need to store it on the User node. In my answer I show you how to get the last key : select last(feed.keys()) from <user-id>. After fetching the last key, you can build a loop that creates the array of elements you want to be retreived like this : select expand(feed[lastkey -2,lastkey-1,lastkey]) from <user-id>

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't used the OrientDB console before. So, what it the lifespan of the var `lastkey`?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Let me look into it a bit and will get back to you.

Comment: So how did you implement your infinite scroll query ? I would be happy to hear it because I am also doing a social network right now...

Comment: Hey Kevin ! I found a solution way more elegant. I was building a string for nothing hahaha. Take a look at my updated answer :-)

Comment: I think your question is answered don't you ?

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB supports pagination: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Pagination.html

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the exact use case here. I want to retrieve nodes that may have different order of their ID (and RID) that were created at different times. But these nodes are linked by a relationship.

Hence, these nodes are in a very long linked list and the only way to get these nodes is to traverse through them.

Comment: Hi @Lvca -- pagination seems to behave a little funky in the current release:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731791/orientdb-automatic-pagination-returning-duplicate-result-short-pages-and-an-in